# Are there any first-person subjective reports from individuals exposed to Agent BZ?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, 1960s, drugs, chemicals

[Agent BZ](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK201480/) is a chemical weapon explored by the US military which induces overwhelming hallucinogenic states.

While there's a fair amount of data on the history of this subjects and the rough pharmacology, I'm interested to see if there are any subjective reports, first-hand experiences of those exposed to this substance.

I've tried searching around; Wikipedia doesn't seem to have anything, though there is a page for Agent BZ. Googling stuff like "Agent BZ subjective effects" or "subjective report" comes up with a lot of dense, dry medical journals talking in terms of observations, not subjective experience.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: "*overwhelming hallucinogenic states, first-hand experiences of those exposed to this substance*": I can think of a few exposed to it and still in politics, science or (show)business... but, hey! no name-calling :D

Comment: Are you looking for "first person" vice "subjective"?  Would that revision potentially get you a better answer?

Comment: I don't think I have anything to add to the question, but that's an awesome screen name.

Comment: @MCW Yeah, I'm looking for a first person, subjective view. "I was exposed to/took this substance and this is what I experienced."

Answer (score 6):

Given that Agent BZ is currently a pharmacological tool, I'm confident that there are.  Given that it is a pharmacological agent, I'm confident that most of the first person records are going to be protected as Personal Health Information(PHI). It is possible you'll find a research paper on [QNB](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ershdb/emergencyresponsecard_29750015.html) that might contain some anonymized summaries.

> Once considered a potential incapacitating agent for military applications, it is currently used as a pharmacological tool (a muscarinic antagonist known as QNB). It produces anticholinergic delirium, a non-specific syndrome of cognitive dysfunction, hallucinations, and inability to perform tasks. Inhalation exposure would likely involve an aerosolized solid.  *[NIH.gov](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK201480/)*

I'd start with the two Ketchum references below, then I'd search on QNB

> Several of the human exposures reported by [Ketchum](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK201480/#) (1963) and [Ketchum](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK201480/#) et al. (1967) were associated with high total response index (TRI) scores indicative of notable cognitive and behavioral effects and some motor-function effects but no apparent serious physiologic responses.

Comment: This is a super valuable insight, I had no idea it was being actively used in a non-military setting! Thank you!